# jQuery get cached value in IE 8.0

Tags: caching, jquery, get

I wrote a simple snippet to load dynamically pages parts as follows:

```
  function LoadParts(container) {
        $("a._Part", container).each(function () {
            element = $(this);
            url = $(this).attr("href");
            $.get(url, null, function (text, status) {
                var c = $(element).parent("span");
                c.html(text);
                LoadParts(c);
            });
        });
    }
```

I was tracing the traffic with Fiddler while I was browsing it using IE 8.0, and I saw a *magic happens here*, for some calls it used a cached value, and for some others got a fresh one.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the ajax method
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax(url, 
   {
       cache: false,
       success: function(){
          //do something
       }
   }
);
```